# How to active div tag with loader class from component typescript in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have component with div tag in containing loader class in HTML template. The loader is active on page loading and once data is retrieved from the server the loader is hided as shown below:

```
<div class="loader" *ngIf="!loadedData"></div>
```

I want to reactive the loader once i click on validate button.

How can I do that in a method called once i click the button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set the property back to false in the button click event, and the div is shown again?

Comment: I suppose you don't want to reset the `loadedData` to `false` when you click on button that validates some input. In this case, keep a separate `loading` variable and let the condition be `*ngIf="loading"`. `loading` will then be set to `false` when the data is loaded, and set to true when you click on the validate button

Comment: @jmdavalos this doesn't work for me

Comment: @yannick also doesn't work as the page is already loaded

Comment: how does it not, can you provide your code?

Comment: @jmdavalos the page is already loaded once i click a button i should see the loader

Comment: see. there's this thing called two-way binding in angular wherein changing the value of the class attribute `loading`, even when the page is already loaded, would affect the value of `loading` in the template and vice versa. when you change the value of `loading` to `true` from within the function that you call when you click the button, it should show the loader again. and i cannot make anymore comment without seeing your actual code

Comment: @jmdavalos totaly agree but how can i  use [(ngModel)] with [hidden] or *ngIf this is the big issue

Comment: i think the big issue here right now is that there obviously is no `[(ngModel)]` in the original post and we keep on asking for your code. can't help you if we can't see how you're implementing the JS/TS side of your app, there's just not enough context

Answer (score 0):

Your div is showed when `loadedData` is set to false. So when the data is retrieved from the server, just to a simple `this.loadedData = false`.

To be clear :

`.html`

```
<button (click)="buttonClickHandler()">Enable loader</button>
```

`.ts`

```
  //Assuming that you do the job in the onInit

  buttonClickHandler(){
    this.loadedData = false;
  }
```

Comment: this is not my issue. my issue is after loding data and have all data in my template once i click a button i want to reactive the loader setted in div tag

Comment: then just set the loadedData to false into a function, I've edited my answer

Comment: So you have a popup now, fine. Can you provide a stackblitz? Can't really help you since you add things on the run.

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me:

component HTML:

```
<div id="loader" class="loader" [hidden]="loading"></div>
```

this loading variable takes `false` as default value and once the data is loaded it takes `true`

component Typescript:

```
showLoader(){
    let divLoader = document.getElementById('loader');
    console.log("this is the div ",divLoader);
    divLoader.removeAttribute("hidden");
    divLoader.classList.add("show-loader");
}
```

styles.css:

```
.show-loder{
  z-index: 9;
}
```